# Jssor slider different height on landscape

Tags: javascript, slider, jssor

I would like to change the height of a 'Nearby Image Partial Visible Slider' in landscape mode, because otherwise the slider is to tall and you have to scoll to much to see the whole image.

I'm using media queries to change the `#slider1_container` height on landscape mode and all the elements inside the `#slider1_container` scale ok; but the `div#slider1_container` height doesn't change, so a white space appears below the images.

I need a function that will scale the `#slider1_container` like it normally does, but it will give it a height of `1000px` for portrait mode and `500px` for landscape mode. 
This is the code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var options = {
        $AutoPlay: false,
        $PauseOnHover: 1, //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slideshow is auto playing, default value is false
        $ArrowKeyNavigation: true, //Allows arrow key to navigate or not
        $SlideWidth: 800, //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, the default is width of 'slides' container
        //$SlideHeight: 300,                                  //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, the default is width of 'slides' container
        $SlideSpacing: 0, //Space between each slide in pixels
        $DisplayPieces: 2, //Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
        $ParkingPosition: 100, //The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled).
        $ArrowNavigatorOptions: { //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
            $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$, //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
            $ChanceToShow: 2, //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
            $AutoCenter: 2, //[Optional] Auto center arrows in parent container, 0 No, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
            $Steps: 1 //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
        }
    };
    var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
    //responsive code begin
    
    function ScaleSlider1() {
        var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
        if(parentWidth) jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(parentWidth, 2000));
        else window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider1, 30);
    }
    ScaleSlider1();
    $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider1);
    $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider1);
    $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider1);
    });
```

And this is the style:

```css
.slider1_container {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slider1_container .slides {
    cursor: move;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
@media all and (orientation: landscape) {
    .slider1_container {
      position: relative;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      width: 1000px;
      height: 500px;
      overflow: hidden;
   }
   .slider1_container .slides {
      cursor: move;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      width: 1000px;
      height: 500px;
      overflow: hidden;
   }
}
```

**Updated code that fixed the problem**

```
<div class="sliderWrapperPadding">
    <div class="sliderWrapperAbsolute">
        <div id="slider1_container">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    .sliderWrapperPadding {
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        clear: both;
        padding-top: 100%;
    }
    .sliderWrapperAbsolute {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .slider1_container {
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 1000px;
        height: 1000px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    @media all and (orientation:landscape) {
        .sliderWrapperPadding {
            padding-top: 50%;
        }
        .slider1_container {
            width: 1000px;
            height: 500px;
        }
</style>
```

Comment: It always keeps aspect ratio while scaling.

Comment: Once jssor is initialized, size would be fully controlled by script and inline style. External css won't work on size anymore.

Comment: `It always keeps aspect ratio while scaling.` The height will change when you scale the `width` by `$ScaleWidth` call. Or you can call `$ScaleHeight` directly.

Comment: Ok, I understand that it always keeps the same aspect ratio while scaling. But what can I do if I need the slider to have square shape on portrait mode and rectangular shape on lanscape mode? Should I just create 2 sliders and show the square one on portrait and the rectangular one on landscape? Or can you tell me how can I change the script to achieve this? Thank you

Comment: You can create a div `(overflow: hidden;)`, and place jssor slider in the div. So you can control the size of the div, and you can scale the slider to fit the size of the div.

Comment: I've created two wrapper divs and it works. I've updated the code with the one that works.